# Unity 2d endless runner level parts not spawning

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am very new to programming.. I tried to make a endless runner with unity and I am at the point now that I want to make platforms to spawn automatically. I followed a tutorial but whenever I reach the end no new platforms are being spawned ):
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TESTGAMEMANAGER : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART = 50f;

    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> levelPartList;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerScript player;

    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPoint").position;

        int startingSpawnLevelParts = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++)
        {
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position(), lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART)
        {
            // Spawn another level part
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnLevelPart()
    {
        Transform chosenLevelPart = levelPartList[Random.Range(0, levelPartList.Count)];
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(chosenLevelPart, lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPoint").position;
    }

    private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart, Vector3 spawnPosition)
    {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        return levelPartTransform;
    }

}
```

It seems like that only at the start there are platforms but after some time I reach the end and fall down );
Anyone know how to fix that?

[Unity Picture with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJIyy.png)

Comment: Looks like they should be just spawning on top of each other. Normally endless runners the base pieces move not the player.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer! If i increase the "PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART" more platforms are being spawned correctly. The only thing that doesn't work is that it's not spawning automatically when the player is at the end. Also I have a script that moves all the platforms so the player is fixed.. What you mean with on top of each other?

Comment: You took the position of the end piece and spawned on it so they would have appeared in the same place.